# How to catch a "load" event on STYLE tag with IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, internet-explorer, jquery-events

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var style = $("<style/>")
    .html("body{background:grey; color:white;} /*and more CSS style*/")
    .on("load", function () {
        console.log("The New style injection has finished to load!");
    });
$("head").append(style);
```

On Chrome, Safari and Firefox browsers the `load` event triggers on time and works perfectly, exactly as expected.
But on Internet Explorer (any version) it doesn't trigger the `load` event at all!

Why doesn't it works on IE?
What is the solution for IE (if any)?

An example that works on all browsers except IE, can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/KWHyZ/2/

Comment: That's the strangest way I've seen jQuery used to alter CSS.

Comment: what does IE dev tools say?

Comment: @j08691, If you inject CSS into a page dynamically, it will take time to apply it (the time depends on the browser's engine). Meanwhile, I don't wish to show the HTML before the CSS is ready, because it looks ugly and not professional. That's why I need to know when the CSS render is ready.

Comment: is this in your head?

Comment: @JayHarris, IE doesn't says anything. It's just doesn't trigger the `load` event.

Comment: @JayHarris, Yes, it's injected into the end of the HEAD tag.

Comment: @j08691, It's not a jQuery's event, but DOMElement's event. It is also works with `document.createElement('style').onload = function(){...}`.

Comment: I put it in jsfiddle with IE and it worked my friend. maybe you don't have jQuery loaded or your script is ahead of jQuery

Comment: @JayHarris, Sorry, but I just tested it with IE10 on jsFiddle, and it doesn't work! http://jsfiddle.net/TWe53/

Comment: @JayHarris, What do you mean?

Comment: This is not a right way to set CSS dynamically. See Adam's answer. Set directly the CSS rules to elements or put them into a new css file and load into the `head`. Prioritize loading CSS rules from external files.

Comment: @AndréTrindadeFigueiredo wrong, the OP's way is actually a better way. Applying styles to individual elements is a really bad idea. A css file is ok but not always the best solution.

Comment: @JayHarris your fiddle doesn't work (tested in IE 10)

Comment: @j08691 that's regular style injection, what part looks strange to you?

Answer (score 2):

I propose a different way altogether of tackling this problem, though I don't have a page with enough css to test it with.

Rather than waiting for the load event to be fired, which, appears not to happen - why not make the content hidden by default, only making it visible with the added css?

That is to say, the following provides an alert and a message on the console in Chrome, but it's never fired in IE. However, since the (pre-existing) css appears before the `<body>` tag, page remains 'blank' until the dynamically added css has loaded.

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function onStyleLoaded()
{
    var mStr = "The New style injection has finished to load!";
    console.log(mStr);
    alert(mStr);
}

function mInit()
{
    var style = newEl('style');
    style.addEventListener('load', onStyleLoaded, false);
    style.innerHTML = ".styleMe{font-weight: bold; color: red;} body{visibility:visible;}";
    document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class='styleMe'>Style this stuff!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @enhzflep.  
I thought about it, but this script is used by a lot of different websites, and controlling the load time of these sites is out of a question. But, thanks! +1 on the creativity. :)

Comment: @SlavikMe - you're welcome. I'm a little unsure about what you mean by "controlling load times of these sites is out of the question" - this code doesn't do anything that controls/effects time. The alert is merely there so I don't have to open the script console to see output. Its as fast as can be, since the browser handles (with it's optimized, native code) all of the display. The key point that I forgot to mention, is that the rule that makes the body visible again is the last one in the added css. Sorry it appears not to help you. Cheers for the creativity vote. :)

Comment: What i meant is that I don't want to control the visible time of the page. 1. This script can be executed later on the page (not only on page loading). 2. Even if it's executed with the page loading, The CSS sometime could take a few seconds until it's ready, and I don't want to make the whole site invisible (because the CSS is usually applied on a specific component on the page). You see what I mean? Look at my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KWHyZ/2/).

Comment: @SlavikMe - :light-bulb!: Ah, now I gotcha. You've explained it perfectly. I didn't even consider such a situation. Interesting question, bookmarked for a later-look.

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding only a couple of CSS rules - do them individually:

```
$('body').css({background:'#000', color:'#fff'});
$('#element').css({color:'#000', textDecoration:'underline'});
//etc...
```

If you're adding a bunch of stuff, then create a stylesheet and load it dynamically onto the page:

```
$('<link/>')
    .attr('href','http://example.com/urltostylesheet.css')
    .attr('rel','stylesheet')
    .attr('type','text/css')
    .appendTo($('head'))
    .on('load',function() {
        // do stuff
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there are two problem: 1. I don't exactly know the content of the CSS data. 2. The CSS content is differ  from user to user (A/B testing purposes). So, applying the CSS on each element or loading it using a LINK tag is not an option. Thanks.